# What is the purpose of TRY_LOOP="20" in the entrypoint.sh file for Airflow?

Tags: docker, airflow

My entrypoint.sh file in Airflow set up starts with a script as posted below:

I can't understand what is the TRY_LOOP="20" supposed to do?

Example:

TRY_LOOP="20"

: "${AIRFLOW_HOME:="/usr/local/airflow"}"

: "${AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY:=${FERNET_KEY:=$(python -c "from cryptography.fernet import Fernet; FERNET_KEY = Fernet.generate_key().decode(); print(FERNET_KEY)")}}"

: "${AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR:=${EXECUTOR:-Sequential}Executor}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The puckel docker image uses the TRY_LOOP variable to re-try connecting to the Postgres Database & Redis 20 times. It is helpful when the DB takes some time to initialize and the port is not yet ready to handle connections.

Code:

https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/bed777970caa3e555ef618d84be07404438c27e3/script/entrypoint.sh#L31-L43

https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/bed777970caa3e555ef618d84be07404438c27e3/script/entrypoint.sh#L31-L43